# Ip address short list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have huge list of ip. I have to remove the last octect. only 3 octects are present after removing(xyz.xyz.xyz). In these 3 octects i have to remove duplicates.
Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some code you have tried to solve it. SO is for suggesting improvements in code, and not to write the code for you

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide some code, but I think this is what you need:

```
IPs = ['111.111.111.111',
          '111.111.111.111',
          '111.111.111.111',
          '111.111.111.111',
          ]
    IPs = [item[:item.rfind('.')] for item in IPs]
    IPs = list(set(IPs))
    print(*IPs)
```

You are asking about the very basics, please try to learn them before asking basic questions.

Comment: @NickVitha , it was a quick solution, check it now.